# Realm Objective‑C How to ignore when written to the database already exists the same primary key?

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

I get data List from Server. They are array of books. I have RLMObjects of books, book, person.

```
@class Person, Book;
@interface Person : RLMObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int age;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger id;
@end
RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(Person)


@interface Book : RLMObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) Person *author;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *price;
@property (nonatomic, strong) RLMArray<Person> *translators;
@end
RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(Book)


@interface Books : RLMObject

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger count;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *year;
@property (nonatomic, strong) RLMArray<Book> *books;
@end

@implementation Person

+ (NSString *)primaryKey {
    return @"id";
}

@end
```

When I get array of books, turn them from dictionary to the Books object. Then add it into realm.

```
[[RLMRealm defaultRealm] transactionWithBlock:^{
        [[RLMRealm defaultRealm] addObject:[Books mj_objectWithKeyValues:responseObject]];
    } error:nil];
```

It crashed.Because there're two books which had same translators. Can't set primary key property 'id' to existing value '1314331'.

So, like this situation, how to put data into RLMRealm and keep every person object is the only one by primaryKey?

Comment: instead of  addObject use addOrUpdateObject method.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
[[RLMRealm defaultRealm] transactionWithBlock:^{
    RLMObject *object = [Books mj_objectWithKeyValues:responseObject];
    [[RLMRealm defaultRealm] addOrUpdateObject:object];
} error:nil];
```

Comment: didn't work . I guess this method only check Books object did exist. It won't check deep inside. The problem is one translator of a book is the same person with a translator of another book, they both are objects of Books property books,   May be I should think about the model design.

Comment: Or you can try creating an object first and then add it to realm

So Instead Of This
[[RLMRealm defaultRealm] transactionWithBlock:^{ [[RLMRealm defaultRealm] addOrUpdateObject:[Books mj_objectWithKeyValues:responseObject]]; } error:nil];

Try this

[[RLMRealm defaultRealm] transactionWithBlock:^{ [[RLMRealm defaultRealm] addOrUpdateObject:[Book createOrUpdateInRealm:realm withValue:responseObject]]; } error:nil];